# Can the performance of PagedList and RecyclerView interaction be improved?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-paging

In my Android app i'm showing data in a `RecyclerView` using Room and the Paging library.

My implementation is quite similar to the example in the `AsyncPagedListDiffer` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/AsyncPagedListDiffer).

The flow is the following:

1. Data is changed in the database
2. A corresponding `Observer` passes the changes to the `Adapter`:

   ```
   myLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
       myAdapter.submitList(it)
   })
   ```
3. The `AsyncPagedListDiffer` calculates the diff and updates the list accordingly

My problem is the performance hit of step 3.

Even if i insert just **one** single item to the top of the list, the differ have to check **all** of the items (which is quite inefficient, especially with larger datasets), whereas a simple `notifyItemInserted(0)` call would be sufficient.

Is there a way around this behavior?

For example, can i tell the differ that it doesn't have to check all of the items? Or any other solutions to this?

I'd really appreciate any advice.